# Profile with CiviGrant custom field, not

Tags: profile, civigrant

I created a small site recently that uses civigrant and the grant applications extension. I created a few custom fields on the grant entity and was able to expose those via a profile to be used in a grant application. So far so good!

After a recent civicrm upgrade to 5.49.5, I'm no longer able to add new custom grant fields to my profile, and when trying to edit the existing ones, they refuse to acknowledge their existence and threaten to disappear.

I've just updated civicrm to 5.51.1 and the applications extension to the latest, and see now change.

Any clues where this comes from or how to fix it? I feel like it's an easy tweak in a db table somewhere, and that it fell out during the extensionization of civigrant at some point ...

Interestingly, the existing grant fields in the profile are working in spite of not being able to edit them. So it's just the admin interface that seems a bit clueless.

Comment: I can recommend webform civicrm - it works with CiviGrant (pre and post extensionization) 

Comment: I've just tried https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and it doesn't have this issue, so it must be specific to my install or has been resolved.

Comment: A fresh install with the same versions as mine doesn't display this issue, so it seems likely to be an upgrade issue with either the core civigrant extension or the contrib civigrant applications extension.

Comment: Uninstalling the grant applications extension removes the grant option when adding a field to a profile, so it seems likely to be an upgrade issue with the civigrant applications extension.

Comment: Here's hoping the extension authors have some clues: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/grantapplications/-/issues/189